# How can I connect two TP-LINKS routers using WAN-WAN?

Tags: networking, router, wan

I'm trying to set up an Internet emulation using 2 TP-LINK routers and 2 computers.

The first computer-router is in LAN: 192.168.0.0

The second computer-router is in LAN: 192.168.1.0

The connection between the two routers is in WAN-WAN and it's: 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.2

I'm not very confortable using GUI (I'm used to CLI but I don't have it here) but I've try to set up statics routes to the other network. My problem is that sometimes I can make pings to the other router WAN IP (10.0.0.1/10.0.0.2) and sometimes I can't. Sometimes I can ping the other subnet and sometimes can't and in conclussion, I don't get a full comunication here. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the devices will do this. As they'll expect routing tables from the 'ISP' and neither of these is going to publish them for the other router.

Comment: You could plug them both in on the lan ports of a 3rd router, this'd likely work as you were expecting. However, the routers may still block/drop packets that are coming from private or even class C addresses on the WAN ports. It's quite normal to do so.